# UINavigationBar appearance in UISplitViewController detail on iPad

Tags: ios, uikit, uinavigationbar, ios15, uinavigationbarappearance

I'm using `UISplitViewController` and customise the appearance of my `UINavigationBar` via `UIAppearance` and its working as expected for the most part.

I want to change the navigation to pure white (Red in the example for debugging reasons)

Only on iPad, the `UINavigationBar` of the detail of the `SplitViewController` seems to have an additional `UIVisualEffectsView` that changes the color of the NavigationBar.
On iPhone, everything looks as expected...

This is how I set the Appearance in the AppDelegate

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
  let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
  navigationBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
  navigationBarAppearance.shadowColor = .clear
  navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .red
  UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
  UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
  UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
  UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

}
```

[image: Screenshot of the App displaying the color of the UINavigationBar]

[image: Screenshot of Reveal showing the UIVisualEffectsView]

How can I remove the UIVisualEffectsView from the NavigationBar in the Detail and make it plain white?